# ASP.NET - Image not rendered at runtime

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Please help me with a weird issue I am facing in my web application. In the scenario below an image (company logo) is not getting rendered at runtime.

I have designed a very simple page named **default2.aspx**. The intention of this page is to work as a maintenance page in case of an application downtime. 
The logic of implementing this by have a SiteIsActive switch key in web.config with "N" representing downtime.

In the Global.asax I have implemented the **"Application_BeginRequest"** method to check for the SiteIsActive flag and redirect to default2.aspx. ***While the functionality is working fine with both the SiteIsActive cases, the image (company logo) is not getting rendered in default2.aspx at runtime.*** ***However when I directly browse the default2.aspx by setting it as startup page the logo/image is displayed at runtime.***

**Note:** This scenario is being tried from within visual studio 2015 and is not yet being deployed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as to why the image is not being rendered when the switch (SiteIsActive = N) and being re-directed to default2.aspx

Code for default2.aspx below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head runat="server">

    <link href="~/Image/BrightSide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <title>AAA</title>

</head>

<body id="bodyindex">

    <div id="wrap" style="width: 1000px;">



        <div id="header">            

            <table style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" width="100%">

                <tbody>

                    <tr>

                        <td width="15%">

                            <img src="~Image/AAA_Image.jpg" /></td>

                        <td width="32%">

                            <h1 style="font: bolder 3.1em 'Trebuchet MS',Arial,Sans-serif;">AAAy</h1>

                        </td>

                        <td align="right" width="53%">&nbsp;</td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>



            <br>

            <br>

        </div>

        <div id="content-wrap">


            <h1 align="center">The AAA website is currently unavailable due to scheduled maintenance.<br />

                <br />

                We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please re-visit the site.

          <!--       <div class="caption" style="height:50px;"><div class="content"></div></div> -->

            </h1>

            <br>

            <br>

            <br>

            <div style="clear: both;">

                <!-- wrap lower portion-->

                <div style="width: 75%; float: left;">

                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                </div>

                <br>

                <!-- content-wrap ends here -->

            </div>

            <!-- footer starts here -->

            <div id="footer">



                <div class="footer-left">

                    <p class="align-left">

                        � 2017 <strong>AAA</strong>

                    </p>

                </div>



                <div class="footer-right">

                    <p class="align-right">&nbsp;</p>

                </div>



            </div>

            <!-- footer ends here -->



            <!-- wrap ends here -->

        </div>



    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Code defined in Application_BeginRequest.

The logic I implemented is within the two comments "// Logic for maintainence page". Also please note I have included some logic for IPAddress exclusion where for such IPs the regular websites will be shown and for others the maintenance page is dispalyed:

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    // Check the application validity

    LicenseHelper.CheckValidity();



    // Enable request debugging



    // Application start events

    FirstRequestInitialization(sender, e);



    CMSRequest.BeforeBeginRequest(sender, e);



    // Check if Database installation needed

    if (InstallerFunctions.InstallRedirect())

    {

        return;

    }



    // Enable debugging

    SetInitialDebug();



    CMSRequest.AfterBeginRequest(sender, e);



    // Logic for maintainence page

    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    string maintenancePage = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Maintenance_RedirectTo"];



    string siteIsActive = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteIsActive"];



    if (siteIsActive != null && siteIsActive.Equals("N", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))

    {

        if (!context.Request.Path.Equals("/" + maintenancePage))

        {

            string exceptionIP = string.Empty;

            string ips = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Maintenance_Redirect_Exceptions"];

            string ipAddress2 = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];



            if (ipAddress2 == null || ipAddress2.ToLower() == "unknown")

                ipAddress2 = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];



            //ipAddress2 = "127.0.0.1";



            if (ips != null)

            {

                System.Collections.Generic.List<string> ipAddressList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(

                                            ips.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));



                if (ipAddressList != null)

                {

                    exceptionIP = ipAddressList.Find(delegate (string ipAddress)

                    {

                        return ipAddress.Equals(ipAddress2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

                    });

                }

            }





            if (exceptionIP == null || exceptionIP.Length <= 0)

            {

                this.Response.Redirect(maintenancePage);

            }

        }

    }

    // Logic for maintainence page

}
```

Comment: Could you share the Application_BeginRequest as well?

Comment: @kblok - Just added the code piece for Application_BeginRequest